# Model properties undefined in Controllers computed property

Tags: ember.js

I have a Controller with a computed property `formattedNotificationTime`. This is supposed to concatenate two properties (`notifHours` and `notifMinutes`) from its underlying model and return the result to the screen.

My problem is that the model properties are always `undefined` when accessed from the controller - to add some confusion to the mix they are returned correctly to the screen when accessed from the template using `{{ model.notifHours }}`

I suspect that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong/have a big misunderstanding somewhere in the following 3 pieces of code:

**Model**

This seems to work find under every other circumstance - an unpopulated instance is loaded initially which is then set by the AJAX request/promise.

```
App.Member = Ember.Object.extend({
    load: function () {
        var member = this;
        return $.ajax({
            url: '/members/' + this.get('id'),
            dataType: 'json'
        }).then(function (m) {
            member.setProperties(m);
            return member;
        });
    }
});
```

**Route**

When entering the route I create an instance of `Member` containing an Id which is then populated in `setupController`. Again, this seems to work in most situations (I have a number of text boxes populated with data from the model on my template).

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Member.create({ id: App.memberId });
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        model.load();
    }
});
```

**Controller**

This is where I have problems... No matter how I try to access `notifHours`/`notifMinutes` from the model, they always return `undefined`. It might be worth mentioning that I've also tried the syntax `.property('model')` without any luck.

I suspect I have the implementation of this computed property fundamentally wrong, I'm just not sure how/why..

```
App.SettingsAccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    formattedNotificationTime: function() {
        return this.get('model.notifHours') + ':' + this.get('model.notifMinutes');
    }.property('formattedNotificationTime')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be in the controller, because you are wrongly stating that property is computed from itself. Try this

```
App.SettingsAccountController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    formattedNotificationTime: function() {
        return this.get('model.notifHours') + ':' + this.get('model.notifMinutes');
    }.property('model.notifHours', 'model.notifMinutes')
});
```